# How to manage @@fetchstatus in two cursors?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I want to execute two procedures which both of them use cursor.
I know @@Fetchstatus is global. after running first Procedure @@FetchStatus value is -1 and by executing the second procedure cursor will not run.

Ho do I manage or rest @@fetchstatus to execute second procedure too in the same connection?

Answer (score 1):

SImple. You can not fetch on 2 sp's at the same time. So it will always show the fetch status of the LAST fetch executed. Use accordingly, i.e. by immediatly evaluating or copying to a variable if needed in a different part.

And it is not global - it is SCOPE specific. It if would be global, it would be one status between connections.